# How to convert a numeric (15,2) to nvarchar(15)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert a `numeric(15,2)` value to a `nvarchar(15)` string.

The value is `132.500m`, I want it the converted value to be `000000000013250`.

I wrote this code but it returns this `000000000000132`.

Code:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE (STR(ROUND(CAST(MonthlyPayment.PaymentAmount AS NUMERIC(18,2)), 0, 1), 15), ' ', 0) 
FROM 
    MonthlyPayment
```

Comment: Hi, please re-check my answer! With very large numbers you might run into exceptions due to `INT`...

Comment: Thanks a lot mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @d DECIMAL(15,2)=132.500;
SELECT REPLACE(STR(CAST(@d*100 AS int),15),' ','0')
```

### UPDATE Thx to Dean!

The code above would break due to an arithmetic overflow exception due to the value range of `INT`. But this works with very big numbers:

```
DECLARE @d DECIMAL(15,2)=1234567890123.45;
SELECT REPLACE(STR(CAST(@d*100 AS BIGINT),15),' ','0')
```

or even bigger :-)

```
DECLARE @d DECIMAL(15,2)=9999999999999.97;
SELECT REPLACE(STR(CAST(@d*100 AS BIGINT),15),' ','0')
```

But their is a tiny issue with `9999999999999.98` and `9999999999999.99`. It works, if you go up to 16 digits with a leading zero...

Comment: Well, since you made a remark to Gordon, your code will fail with a larger number as well. Try bigint to be safe..

Comment: Hi @dean, good catch, thank you! See my updated... At least the great Gordon himself has made the same mistake :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 15) +
             CAST(CAST(MonthlyPayment.PaymentAmount * 100 as INT) as VARCHAR(15)),
             15)
```

That is:

- Multiply by 1000
- Convert to an integer
- Left pad with zeros

Comment: Hi, I do not like the approach with `RIGHT`. In this case it might be Okay due to the 15 digits, but if the number exceeds, it will be cut without an error. I prefer the approach with `STR` which will return a chain of `*` if the number is to big...

Comment: Btw: Your code pads with blanks and not with zeros and - from OP - I think that `*100` is what is needed...